# Selecting with modified preorder tree traversal when there are multiple trees

Tags: php, mysql, sql, tree

I have implemented a Modified Preorder Tree Traversal [as explained here](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/) for optimalisation reasons. My table is something like this:

```
+----+-----------+------+-------+
| id | parent_id | left | right |
+----+-----------+------+-------+
|  1 |      NULL |    1 |     4 | 
|  2 |         1 |    2 |     3 | 
|  3 |      NULL |    1 |     4 | 
|  4 |         3 |    2 |     3 | 
+----+-----------+------+-------+
```

I.e. there exist an arbitrary number of trees in the table. If a node's parent id is null, then that automatically means the node is the very base of its tree.

The article points out that one can select all a node's descendants very simply:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
    left > ? 
    AND
    right < ?
```

Now my problem is that the selection is obviously going to include nodes of other trees. After all, I haven't even specified a tree to begin with. Is it possible to just select the nodes from one specified tree with this model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't start new tree with `left` = 1. Use MAX(`right`) + 1 for `left` value. This will not affects other node manipulations, and trees will be separated by left-right range.